# using linear programming to find median

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, median

I'm trying to figure out how to transform a median solving problem for a list of number x to linear programming and with standard form of $$\text{min }c^Tx \text{ s.t: } Ax\le b \text{ and }x \geq 0$$

I know that we need to use l1 norm to find median and median = $$argmin \sum|m-xi|$$

but I'm not sure how to transform this absolute value to an optimization question in standard form.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you are trying to find the median just sort the list and then pick the middle element. You don't need to put this into an optimization solver.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_i = |m-x_i|$, then the problem becomes

$$\min_{m,z_1, \ldots, z_n} \sum_i z_i$$

subject to $z_i \ge m-x_i, z_i \ge x_i -m, \forall i \in \{1, n\}$.

I will leave the task of converting it to standard form to you.

Comment: This makes so much sense! thank you